# using java's interface as type and instantiating it

Tags: java, android, types, interface, instantiation

I have heard a lot that we cannot use Java's interface to instantiate it as a type but when I tried the following code it did not complain. Why?

```
OnClickListener lis1 = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
};
```

As `OnClickListener` is a interface, shouldn't it complain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an example of an [Anonymous Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) (excerpted),

> Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They are like local classes except that they do not have a name. Use them if you need to use a local class only once.